# How to use the PubMed API to search for an article with an exact title?

Tags: http-get, pubmed

I'm trying to use the PubMed API to search for articles with an exact title. As an example, I want to search for the title

```
The cost-effectiveness of mirtazapine versus paroxetine in treating people with depression in primary care
```

I want up to 1000 results in JSON format, so I know that the first part of my URL should look like this:

```
http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=1000&term=
```

How do I add a title search as a GET parameter?

I've been using the Pubmed [advanced search constructor](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed), and that suggests that the query should look like `The cost-effectiveness of mirtazapine versus paroxetine in treating people with depression in primary care[Title]`.

But if I try just adding that to the URL `term=`, PubMed tries to break down the title into all kinds of peculiar queries:

```
http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=1000&term=The%20cost-effectiveness%20of%20mirtazapine%20versus%20paroxetine%20in%20treating%20people%20with%20depression%20in%20primary%20care[Title]
```

How can I specify an exact title as a GET param?

Answer (score 6):

Use `field=title`

http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=1000&term=The%20cost-effectiveness%20of%20mirtazapine%20versus%20paroxetine%20in%20treating%20people%20with%20depression%20in%20primary%20care&field=title

Check out ESearch API for more information:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#_chapter4_ESearch_

Comment: This has been scratching my head for a couple of days!

Answer (score 3):

Use `+` instead of `%20` (space).

For example:

http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=1000&term=cost+effectiveness+of+mirtazapine[title]

Comment: Thanks - but the `translationset` field in the results suggests that the query is still being broken down into lots of alternate queries, rather than just being a pure phrase search.